Why does my Sublime Text2 wrap prematurely when encountering some symbols like ).?
I have enabled the auto wrap feature. This function usually runs normally. But sometimes there may be some lines that break prematurely.Lines with black dots need attention.What can be done to solve this problem? The picture

The test text(Sorry you have to decodeURIComponent it cause I cant post CJK characters in SO)

"%E5%8F%8D%E5%BC%8F%E8%84%82%E8%82%AA%E5%B8%B8%E8%A7%81%E4%BA%8E%E7%83%98%E7%84%99%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81(%E9%9D%A2%E5%8C%85%E3%80%81%E8%9B%8B%E7%B3%95%E3%80%81%E9%A5%BC%E5%B9%B2%E3%80%81%E6%B4%BE%E3%80%81%E5%86%B7%E5%86%BB%E6%8A%AB%E8%90%A8%E7%AD%89%EF%BC%89%E3%80%81%E6%B2%B9%E7%82%B8%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81(%E8%96%AF%E7%89%87%E3%80%81%E9%BA%BB%E8%8A%B1%E3%80%81%E7%94%9C%E7%94%9C%E5%9C%88%E3%80%81%E7%82%B8%E9%B8%A1%E5%9D%97%E7%AD%89)%EF%BC%8C%E5%B7%A7%E5%85%8B%E5%8A%9B%E7%B3%96%E3%80%81%E7%83%AD%E5%B7%A7%E5%85%8B%E5%8A%9B%E7%B2%89%E3%80%81%E9%80%9F%E6%BA%B6%E5%92%96%E5%95%A1%E3%80%81%E5%A5%B6%E8%8C%B6%E7%AD%89%E3%80%82%0A%E4%BA%BA%E4%B8%BA%E5%AF%BC%E8%87%B4%E7%9A%84%E5%8F%8D%E5%BC%8F%E8%84%82%E8%82%AA%E5%8C%85%E6%8B%AC%EF%BC%9A%0A%E2%9A%AB%E6%88%91%E5%9B%BD%E8%A7%84%E5%AE%9A%E5%A6%82%E6%9E%9C%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E5%90%AB%E5%8F%8D%E5%BC%8F%E8%84%82%E8%82%AA(%E9%85%B8)%E3%80%81%E6%B0%A2%E5%8C%96%E6%88%96%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%E6%B0%A2%E5%8C%96%E6%B2%B9%E8%84%82%E7%9A%84%E5%8E%9F%E6%96%99%EF%BC%8C%E5%B0%B1%E5%BF%85%E9%A1%BB%E6%A0%87%E5%87%BA%E5%8F%8D%E5%BC%8F%E8%84%82%E8%82%AA%E9%85%B8%E7%9A%84%E5%90%AB%E9%87%8F%E3%80%82%E5%90%AB%E9%87%8F%E7%AC%A6%E5%90%88%EF%BC%9C0.3g/100g%EF%BC%8C%E5%B0%B1%E5%8F%AF%E4%BB%A5%E6%A0%87%E2%80%9C0%E2%80%9D%E3%80%82%0A%E2%9A%AB%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%E6%A0%87%E5%87%BA%E5%8F%8D%E5%BC%8F%E8%84%82%E8%82%AA%E5%90%AB%E9%87%8F%E4%B8%8D%E7%AD%89%E4%BA%8E%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%EF%BC%8C%E6%AF%94%E5%A6%82%E6%95%A3%E7%A7%B0%E7%B3%95%E7%82%B9%E3%80%81%E9%A4%90%E5%8E%85%E3%80%82%E5%A6%82%E6%9E%9C%E5%8E%9F%E6%96%99%E4%B8%AD%E6%9C%89%E5%A4%A7%E9%87%8F%E9%BB%84%E6%B2%B9%E3%80%81%E5%A5%B6%E6%B2%B9%E7%9A%84%E9%A3%9F%E7%89%A9%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%96%E8%80%85%E6%98%AF%E6%B2%B9%E7%82%B8%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81%E5%A6%82%E9%BA%BB%E8%8A%B1%E3%80%81%E8%96%AF%E6%9D%A1%E7%AD%89%EF%BC%8C%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E5%90%AB%E6%9C%89%E8%BE%83%E5%A4%9ATFA%E3%80%82%E5%A4%A9%E7%84%B6%E5%A5%B6%E6%B2%B9%E3%80%81%E9%BB%84%E6%B2%B9%E7%9A%84TFA%E5%90%AB%E9%87%8F%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87%E4%B8%BA2.53g/100g%5B1%5D%E3%80%82%E5%A4%A9%E7%84%B6%E5%A5%B6%E6%B2%B9%E3%80%81%E9%BB%84%E6%B2%B9%E9%83%BD%E6%98%AF%E5%8A%A8%E7%89%A9%E6%B2%B9%E8%84%82(%E4%B9%B3%E8%84%82)%EF%BC%8C%E8%BF%98%E6%9C%89%E8%BE%83%E5%A4%9A%E7%9A%84%E9%A5%B1%E5%92%8C%E8%84%82%E8%82%AA%E5%92%8C%E8%83%86%E5%9B%BA%E9%86%87%E3%80%82"

